# Version number issue with App Store submission

Tags: ios, app-store, submission

I encountered a very strange question. I currently have a product with version 1.01 in Apple App Store, and when I try to submit an app with version 1.1, and I encountered this error:

[image: 1st Error Message]

This means 1.01 has been interpreted as 1.1? Now my problem is I can't remove the 1.1 build (so to rename it as 1.2) and I can't submit... what should I do?

If I set the build to 2 or 3 (version as 1.1) I got the following error message:

[image: 2nd Error Message]

Comment: if you want to publish it as version 1.1, just change the build number (not version) to 2, 3 ...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I set up build as 2 or 3 and I got another error message (please see updated description).

Comment: Did you publish the 1.1 version to AppStore? If the 1.1 version is publishing in AppStore, you must change your version to 1.1.1 or 1.2, that higher than 1.1

Comment: If you 1.1 has approved, but not yet publishing, you can cancel the approved, and up the next build to AppStore

Comment: No. As mentioned 1.01 was approved, not 1.1. I am now creating an entry for 1.1 submission.

Comment: `1.01` has same with `1.1`, you mean `1.0.1`?

Comment: Which is the problem. The approved version is 1.01, and now I am in the process of submitting 1.1 (and cannot).

Comment: You must choose the next version is 1.1.1 or 1.2 :(

Comment: That's the problem - you can't change the version before submission to other build, and you cannot delete and resubmit.

Comment: Your version 1.01 (build 1) was interpreted as version 1.1 since leading zeros are stripped from numbers. So 1.01 -> 1.1. Your next update must both increase the version and build. So anything greater than 1.1 such as 1.1.1 or 1.2, etc. for the version. At the same time, increment the build number from 1 to 2, etc.

Comment: That's the problem, now there is indeed a 1.1 build in process - before submission - and I can't delete it and I can't change the number to 1.2?

Comment: @LimThyeChean : you can cancel the process or even approved build whenever you want. Just cancel it and upload an new build with build number increase

Comment: How do you cancel/remove the 1.1 build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.01 is the same as version 1.1 because the leading zero is ignored. Your new version must be higher, say 1.2

In App Store connect, select your new iOS version, 1.1 and change its version number, under "General App Information" to 1.2 and save your changes.

You can now upload version 1.2. build 1